# Safari handles z-index otherwise than Chrome (rotationY)

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, z-index

I'm creating 3D flip cards with CSS3.

In Google Chrome it does exactly what it should do, but Safari seems to have some problems with the z-index.

Safari behavior (wrong): https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4O9N.png

Chrome behavior (correct): https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX2Jw.png

Example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Widmore/XJFAy/7/

Anyone familiar with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a `z-index: auto;` or  `z-index: 0;` to outer elements.

Comment: I created a JSfiddle with the code conflicting my problem http://jsfiddle.net/Widmore/XJFAy/7/

Comment: Instead on stacking things with z-index use translate3d(x,y,z). Your code seems too complicated for a basic simple thing you try to do.